Problems converting to Game.csv using Unreal4 UnrealLocres
I want to find the Game.locres of an Unreal 4 game, convert it to Game.csv, translate it, and then make locres again, but every time I convert the locres with UnrealLocres, it reverts to the original before translation and the patch is not applied. ㅠㅠ Game.locres.new is created and I know I can use that, but it keeps reverting to English... I've searched for this with as many keywords as I can think of, but I don't see any signs of improvement, so I'm asking...
